# Unable to install dcos-cli on Mac OSX

Tags: dcos

DCOS provides the following installation command to install the cli tool:

```
mkdir -p dcos && cd dcos && 
curl -O https://downloads.dcos.io/dcos-cli/install.sh && 
bash ./install.sh . https://mydomain.co && 
source ./bin/env-setup
```

However, when I run this on my Mac, it fails with the following:

```
mkdir -p dcos && cd dcos &&
 | →   curl -O https://downloads.dcos.io/dcos-cli/install.sh &&
 | →   bash ./install.sh . https://mydomain.co &&
 | →   source ./bin/env-setup
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  5163  100  5163    0     0   6460      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  6469
Installing DC/OS CLI from PyPI...

New python executable in /Users/petr/dcos/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/petr/dcos/bin/dcos", line 7, in <module>
    from dcoscli.main import main
  File "/Users/petr/dcos/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dcoscli/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from dcos import config, constants, emitting, errors, http, subcommand, util
  File "/Users/petr/dcos/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dcos/config.py", line 10, in <module>
    from dcos import constants, jsonitem, subcommand, util
  File "/Users/petr/dcos/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dcos/subcommand.py", line 12, in <module>
    from subprocess import PIPE
ImportError: cannot import name PIPE
```

When I run the same command on Ubuntu, it works just fine. Any idea what the root cause is?

Comment: I should add that when I activate the virtualenv environment and start the Python console, I can import subprocess.PIPE no problem. It's difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the issues I've seen around installing the DC/OS CLI on OS X had a root cause related to the [prerequisites](https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/usage/cli/install/) not met. That said, in DC/OS 1.8 we introduced [binaries](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/usage/cli/install/) for the CLI (exactly to avoid situations you're describing).

Comment: Thank you! I +1'ed this answer as a solid workaround. I am still curious if someone posts a direct solution to the above problem.